# getSupportActionBar() returns Null in Android app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I'm trying to make an action with tabs in Android Studio but `getSupportActionBar()` always returns null.

I just want a simple actionbar with 3 tabs where i can click on but neither the actionbar or the tabs are appearing.

This is my code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab == null)
    {
        Log.d("test", "failed");
        return;
    }
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
{
    int nTabSelected = tab.getPosition();
    switch (nTabSelected)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
{
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
{
}

}
```

I have already tried a lot of things i saw on internet like `getActionBar()` or a totally different code but nothing seems to work and i always have the `function` who return `null`.

I'm working under API 19.

Comment: Which theme have you set for your app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to change

```
/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar
```

by

```
/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

in the manifest.

Thanks to Michael for helping me.

Comment: Awesome kickoff answer